# Angular 2 prevent x-xsrf-token to be added on single http request

Tags: angular, x-xsrf-token

I have a web app where I need to make a request to a webservice outside of my page.

This request is made from within a restricted page, and because of this, I have a `x-xsrf-token` set, to autenticate my user on my webpage. This is working.

But I also need to make a request to a webservice outside of my page, but it does not accept `x-xsrf-token`, given me this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "https://webservice-here..." Request header field X-XSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

But since I'm inside a restricted area, I don't know how to solve this issue... This is my `http` service:

```
apiCustom(url: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.delete('x-xsrf-token');

    return this._http.get(url, {
        headers: headers
    }).map(response => response.json()).do(data => {
        return data;
    }).catch(this.handleErrors);
}
```

I tried to delete the `x-xsrf-token` (also tried just `xsrf-token`) manually, but it didn't worked.

Is there a way to solve this?